# Идея для проекта

Tags: проект, opensource, c++

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой проект по программированию можно реализовать?
Требования к проекту: не слишком простой и не слишком сложный (средней сложности для старшеклассника/студента-первокурсника); интересный; не требующий очень много времени для реализации (время - 6 месяцев); скорей всего будет open source и 99%, что некоммерческий.

Мои способности: знаю C++ (основные инструменты языка (кроме STL) знаю, но практики пока не хватает), C (хуже, чем C++).

P.S. Если что - готов выучить еще какой-то язык программирования или технологию.

Comment: Лучше сначала выучить как следует хотя бы один язык программирования, а потом уже пытаться что-то сделать.

Comment: >Мои способности: знаю C++ (уровень не важен, все-равно буду учить),

УБИЛО!

из этого получится

>ка'кой проект

Comment: Вот это не совсем понимаю.

    C (хуже, чем C++)

Comment: Мои способности: знаю C++ (уровень не важен, все-равно буду учить) - основные инструменты языка (кроме STL) знаю, но практики пока не хватает.

C (хуже, чем C++) - С более низкоуровневый чем С++, хотя С++ и является надмножеством С, поэтому знаю его хуже.

Comment: Поскольку требования к проекту почтеннейшей публике неизвестно, то публика затрудняется с советами. ЧТО это должно быть? Приложение с меню, панелями, боксами и пр. прибамбасами или консольное нечто, работающее "в один темп"?

Comment: В серьезном программировании на С++ без STL делать нечего.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше, для начала, напишите к примеру будильник, калькулятор или какой-нибудь шифратор данных. Также можно попробовать написать какую-нибудь небольшую игру (пятнашки, как вариант).

И, по моему мнению, если писать какой-то проект, то в первую очередь нужно, чтобы он был нужен вам самим. Тогда и другим, он скорее всего, будет нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать какую-нибудь программу для [стеганографии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), это довольно интересно. Правда, таких программ уже дофига, но всегда можно найти какой-нибудь формат файла, для которого оно еще не было реализовано.

Более сложный вариант: возьмите какого-нибудь чатбота, библиотеку для работы с jabber и слепите программу, которая будет имитировать разговор и в процессе передавать секретные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это достаточно просто, но попробуйте сделать API подобный malloc()/free() для работы в сегментах shared memory.

Несколько процессов (желательно независимых, т.е. без общего предка) должны согласовано пользоваться этим API для общих сегментов.

Большая проблема тут в том, что один и тот же сегмент в разных процессах может отображаться на разные адреса.

[Эта разработка](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/mm/) требует обшего предка.